What do Efron & Tibshirani mean by the 'empirical exponential family' in the textbook 'Introduction to the Bootstrap'?
I would like to understand what Efron & Tibshirani mean by 'empirical exponential family' in the textbook 'Introduction to the Bootstrap' (formula 21.84 for instance)?
The explanation there is too abbreviated and/or vague for me and the deeper research articles on the topic look challenging to approach.
I'd be grateful to have the basics: A family of distributions consists of distributions. Those distributions are probability measures over a space. What is the space here that the distributions are over(defined on)?  It appears to be a high dimensional product of points from the empirical distribution, but I'm not sure.
How do they calculate the Fisher information for \eta here? (Formula 21.86)
Are they using the empirical exponential family as the distribution of the data (x_i's), the distribution for the sufficient statistics calculated from the data (the q's) or both?
Many thanks if you can give a simple, accessible answer, including or completing anything I've misunderstood or left out. I understand answers could go very deep into empirical likelihood, entropy and divergence measurements, etc. That's great if you want to include it as extra, but please do not make it a prerequisite for understanding the basic points.

The "space" almost certainly is the real numbers with its usual Lebesgue measure.  Please don't require readers to reference the text: give us enough context for your question to stand on its own.

Thanks, but that does not seem to be the right answer. Even the empirical distribution is over a discrete set with counting measure.   As for the reference to the text, the text not necessary to understand my question about the definition of the term. The term 'empirical exponential family' is used in multiple research papers in the empirical likelihood field, so experts in the field should be familiar with it. Thanks anyway for engaging.

You seem to misunderstand.  The empirical distribution is defined over $\mathbb R,$ just like any other univariate real-valued distribution. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73623 for an explanation.

Okay, let's clarify terminology. I said 'over' before and maybe that was too sloppy. Yes the empirical cdf is defined on R. I meant 'with respect to which measure does it have a density/ is it absolutely continuous'? The empirical distribution does not have a density with respect to Lebesgue measure on R, but it does wrt counting measure on the set of data points.

Here is another paper that uses the empirical exponential family: https://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A10n210.pdf

Why would absolute continuity (or lack thereof) be relevant in this context?  An explanation of the ECDF as a nonparametric MLE appears here on CV at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91953.  "Nonparametric" in this fully general setting allows the target distribution to be any distribution on $\mathbb R,$ without restriction to absolutely continuous (or discrete, or whatever) distributions.
